# Web Scraping the list of smart watches from ebay

Tags: web-scraping

From the given link : https://www.ebay.com/b/Smart-Watches/178893/bn_152365 
and
List out the details of all the smartwatches and their specifications and display them in a tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details and characteristics can be obtained by writing something like this:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const MAIN_URL = "https://www.ebay.com/b/Smart-Watches/178893/bn_152365";

const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/539.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A",
  },
};

function getLinks(searchResultsUrl) {
  return axios.get(searchResultsUrl, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(function ({ data }) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const links = [];

    $(".s-item__link").each(function (i, el) {
      links[i] = $(el).prop("href");
    });

    return links;
  });
}
```

This will give you links to each product. Next, you will need to run each link in a parser like this:

```js
function getSpecs(productUrls) {
  return productUrls.map((url, i) => {
    return axios.get(url).then(function ({ data }) {
      const specs = [];
      const labels = [];

      let $ = cheerio.load(data);

      $(".attrLabels").each(function (index, element) {
        const label = $(element)
          .text()
          .replace(/\s/gi, " ")
          .replace(/  /gi, "")
          .replace(": ", "");

        const spec = $(element)
          .next()
          .find("span:not(#readFull)")
          .text()
          .replace(/\s/gi, " ")
          .replace(/  /gi, "");

        labels[index] = label;
        specs[index] = spec;
      });

      const finish = {
        link: url,
      };

      for (let j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
        finish[labels[j]] = specs[j];
      }

      return finish;
    });
  });
}

function logSpecs(specs) {
  console.log(specs);
}

getLinks(MAIN_URL)
  .then(getSpecs)
  .then((promises) => Promise.all(promises))
  .then(logSpecs)
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);

    process.exit(1);
  });
```

You can see how it works [here](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/web-scraping-ebay#index.js).

Output:

```
{
  link: "https://www.ebay.com/itm/233956373339?hash=item3678e2f35b:g:srgAAOSwKUFggjLm&var=533600782928",
  "Condition:":
    "A brand-new, unused, unopened, undamaged item in its original packaging (where packaging is applicable). Packaging should be the same as what is found in a retail store, unless the item is handmade or was packaged by the manufacturer in non-retail packaging, such as an unprinted box or plastic bag. See the seller's listing for full details.See all condition definitions- opens in a new window or tab",
  Brand: "HuaweiHuawei",
  Marke: "Huawei",
  Model: "Band 6",
  Armbandmaterial: "Silikon",
  "Case Size": "22 mm",
  Modell: "Band 6",
  "Compatible Operating System": "Android, iOS - Apple",
  "Kompatibles Betriebssystem": "Android, iOS - Apple",
  "Band Material": "Silicone",
}
```